# Did Soviet propaganda assert that the Jews lived badly/poorly in Israel?

Tags: soviet-union, israel, propaganda

To my knowledge, there was a lot of anti-Israel propaganda that emphasized

- Israeli militarism.
- Suppression of the Arab locals.
- Israel being a puppet of the US.
- Israel being friendly with the former Nazis, for instance, in FRG.

At the same time, the Soviet government initially objected to Jewish emigration to Israel, but then reluctantly allowed it.

In these circumstances it would look logical that the Soviet government would try to convince Soviet Jews that they would live badly and poorly in Israel if they decided to emigrate. But I do not know a single Soviet propaganda piece with such stance.

Are there any known such pieces of propaganda, that would emphasize poverty in Israel, anti-immigrant attitude of the local Israelis, housing shortage, etc?

Comment: By chance, what I think is a mis-spelling in your title (and text) gives an opposite impression to what you mean: I suspect you mean "emphasized". ("Empathized" means "has empathy/sympathy for", which I gather is not what you mean...) I hesitate to change anything, though.

Comment: @paulgarrett hanks, fixed

Comment: Soviet propaganda was not made by idiots. They perfectly understood that those who moved to Israel kept correspondence with their friends and relatives remaining in Soviet Union, and that such statements would sound implausible.

Comment: @Alex why, if they are absolutely real even now?

Comment: @Alex People who emigrated ito Israel in the 1980/90s without selling their real estate in countries of origin, had to take mortgages in Israel for up to 20 years.

Comment: @Anixx: I did not understand your first remark: did you want to say that Russian propaganda nowadays is made by idiots? I don't think so. My experience shows that 70 or 80% of Russians believe it.

Comment: @Alex East German propaganda had lots of stories about life in West Germany was bad. Unemployment, lack of worker's rights, drugs , homelessness etc. Although East Germany was full of people who had relatives in the west.

Comment: Quite a few Jews who left USSR failed in live up to their own expectations in USA and Israel and asked the Soviet authorities for a permission to return (in exchange for participating in anti-emigration propaganda). I remember seeing them in a soviet propaganda movie. They were derisively called "дважды евреи советского союза"....

Comment: @Alex I meant that such points would be truthful as they are truthful now.

Comment: @sds that's not because conditions in those countries were bad, but because expectations were unrealistic. Which shows the reverse of what the question asks, if anything

Comment: I guess the Soviet authorities started allowing emigration to Israel to be rid of a potentially troublesome group within their population they had trouble infiltrating and controlling (because they were pretty tight knit, centuries of persecution had done that). Trying to then keep them from getting out would have been counterproductive.

Comment: @jwenting: That would be a wrong guess. However, you are correct in the context of, say, Poland.

Comment: @jwenting no. The Soviet government definitely did not mean to get rid of the Jews. Even when emigration was allowed, it was conjugated with big obstacles, including, for instance, that a large proportion of Jews were given "clearance" to access fake "state secrets" which prohibited travel abroad (but gave a bit rised salary). There is no real reason why such huge masses would need access to classified information.

Comment: @jwenting: indeed, but why should that stop Soviet propaganda?

Comment: There are many example of the USSR, and other Communist countries, using real examples of things in capitalist countries for propaganda without realizing that people would notice other aspects.  For instance, the USSR once showed some footage of strike breaking in the US, and what the Soviets chiefly noticed was that all the workers had good shoes.  Therefore, unreality was not always an obstacle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a short answer (I will add more detail and background when I have more time):

One of the most "comprehensive" examples of such propaganda is

“The White Book: Evidence, Facts, Documents.”  Moscow, 1979. 280 pages.
("Белая книга: свидетельства, факты, документы", M., 1979.)

You can enjoy reading it (in Russian) here: gumer.info/bibliotek_Buks/History/Article/bel_kn.php.

According to the abstract of the book:

“This book contains evidence, facts and documents about lack of basic rights and oppression in the capitalist world of persons, who left the USSR. It tells how the fake freedoms of the individual in the West under closer examination turn out to be a cover for unemployment, social inequality and humiliation.” [The translation is mine.]

While there is no word "Jew" or "Israel" in the title/abstract, this is what the book is primarily about. Its primary purpose was to discourage Soviet Jews from emigration. The book is a long and detailed version of the propaganda articles/movies that sds mentioned in his comment. The book is clever and was not aimed at idiots.

The original "White Book" was followed in 1985 by the "White Book": New facts, evidence, documents," Moscow, 1985. 302 pages. ("Белая книга. Новые факты, свидетельства, документы." М., 1985.)

A funny thing about both "white books" was that they became bestsellers among Soviet Jews planning emigration since they contained at least *some* information about life of Jews abroad, as well as excerpts from publications that were otherwise illegal in USSR (such as Efraim Sevela's books written in the US).